# How to get the font size set in the Textview

Tags: android, textview, text-size

I am using the typeface in my text view and it is all looking good. Now I want to set the seekbar which will help the user to adjust the text size under the text view.

I have just used the seekbar and played with it. this is how I am using my Seekbar to make the text larger

```
/// SeekBar Progress

    sk.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int p=0;


        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(p<30)
            {
                p=30;
                sk.setProgress(p);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            p=progress;
            myTextView.setTextSize(p);
        }
    });
```

this is working and changing the size of text in the text view, But now there comes the problem :

Problem :

Problem is , the size is increasing and decreasing also when we take the seek bar to the left from its mid point. where as I want to set the minimum and maximum value.  So to set the minimum and maximum I need to get the size of text inside the text view . and I have not found any method to get the textsize like for example **myTextview.getTextSize()** , there is no such method like it.

Let me tell you I am setting the size of the text view from the dimens file in the different values folder for supporting all the device and to make my text look good on tablets and small devices.

So now All I need to get is My text size inside the Text view . Please help me in getting the text size. thank you.

Comment: Hmm, how do you mean there is no such method like `TextView.getTextSize()`, take a look at [that](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTextSize%28%29)  :)

Answer (score 3):

There is `TextView.getTextSize()`. You can also go `TextView.getPaint().getTextSize()`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
text_one.setText("your text");
text_one.measure(0, 0);       //must call measure!
text_one.getMeasuredHeight(); //get height
text_one.getMeasuredWidth();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do check that your `myTextView` is indeed `TextView` and not just `View` when you initialize it. e.g.

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(yourTextViewId);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest answer is

```
myTextView.getTextSize();
```

Actually I was casting my value wrong. and Now it is solved. after doing this

```
 float size = myTextView.getTextSize();
```